# Glossy Bake with Principled

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I'm trying to emulate a substance with Blender.
While I am playing with this I see that there is a problem, Glossy with Principled have a problem... is white or Black... not grayScale.

[image]

If Metallic and Specular are Zero, the bake is Zero.
If Metallic or Specular are greater than Zero, like 0.01 The bake is White.

I do not want to report it until I confirm that it is an error. What do you think?

With glossy node works fine!

[image]

[image]

SCENE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ubv3rmxrrcl4ww6/SE.blend?dl=0